# Vue nested v-for how?

Tags: nested

i'm try render nested list, but it does not work out..

my example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGKGGN
   My object

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "label": "3",
          "value": "cca88ef0-8b08-4b48-ac08-78f80f4ff0a0"
        }
      ],
      "label": "2",
      "value": "f874ad2b-dd02-4cbe-992c-0db6a75e88e0"
    }
  ],
  "id": "f3f58a52-f686-40d4-9d16-5bc623d4607c",
  "label": "1",
  "value": "f3f58a52-f686-40d4-9d16-5bc623d4607c"
}
```

try

```
            <Form ref="formInline" :model="formInline" :rules="ruleInline">

            <FormItem prop="catygory" v-for="(post, index) in posts" >

                <Input  type="text" v-model="post.label"   placeholder="name"><Icon type="ios-moon-outline" slot="prepend"></Icon>


                </Input>


            </FormItem>        

            <FormItem>
                <Button type="primary" @click="toLoading('formInline', marker)"> change</Button>
            </FormItem>
        </Form>
```

not worked :(

i'm try like post[0].label not work , please help

Comment: you need to use recursive component which component v-for's children list.
if the v-for item have children ket which is not empty instead of v-for render same component and pass the children list as prop

Comment: please could you make an example for us?

Comment: yes tomorrow maybe